# Watching a deleted model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript

Consider this psuedo-code:

```
$scope.model = [{ A: 'a', B: 'b' }, { A: 'c', B: 'd' }];

$scope.$watchCollection('model', (model) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < model.length; i += 1) {
    $scope.$watch('model[' + i + '].A', () => ...);
  }
});
```

What happens the watch expression if I `delete $scope.model[1]`? Would it be a "memory leak", a zombie, or some other leakiness?

**Edit** This method offers a terrible solution to an already solved problem. I ended up using angularjs equality check instead of reference check. Refer to the documentation for $watch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `$watch` and `$watchcollection` continue to watch during digest cycles. If the item of interest becomes defined again, the `$rootScope` executes the registered listener function. You can de-register the watcher by calling the de-register function that was returned when the `$watch` was registered. (You **did** save it, didn't you?)

```
var deRegisterFn = $scope.$watchCollection('model', function (newValue) {
      console.log(newValue);
});

delete $scope.model;
deRegisterFn();
```

Otherwise the watcher remains until the scope is destroyed.

For more information on `$watch`, see the [AngularJS $rootScope.scope API Reference -- $watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch).

BTW, your example, adding watchers inside a listening function is very strange. AngularJS is not jQuery and even in the jQuery community there are people who discourage binding and unbinding of listeners. Some even calling it an **Anti-pattern**.

### Update: objectEquality AKA Deep-Watch

`$watch(watchExpression, listener, [objectEquality]);`

- When `objectEquality == true`, inequality of the `watchExpression` is determined
       according to the [angular.equals](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals) function. To save the value of the object for
      later comparison, the [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) function is used. This therefore means that
      watching complex objects will have adverse memory and performance implications.

For performance reasons the `$watch` function uses a "shallow watch". The author of the question needed a "deep watch" of his object. Being unaware of the "objectEquality" option, also known as (AKA) the "deep watch" option, he solved his problem by adding and removing watches on properties of his model. The "deep watch" option solved his problem in a cleaner, more elegant manner. Thus obviating the need to add and remove watches.

For more information on `$watch`, see the [AngularJS $rootScope.scope API Reference -- $watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch).

Comment: Thank you! I _did_ save the watcher, so I'll make sure to invoke the function.

Comment: The reason why it's implemented that way is because I want to update the model when `A` updated, or the collection is changed. Is this achievable without using listeners?

Comment: You can  set `$watch` to do a so-called "deep watch" by setting the third argument to `true`. `$scope.$watch("model", listenerFn, true);`. See the Docs for more info.

Comment: Thank you, @georgeawg! :) I'll look at it!